# I want to know how to make cars wait in parking untill they are called by the next parking lot in anylogic software?

Tags: anylogic, timedelay, traffic-simulation

I am working on anylogic software.In the road traffic library I used delay block to make the cars waiting in one parking lot.I want them to move from one parking to next parking lot and I want to make them wait in that parking lot until the next parking lot is free. Which block should I use and how to call the cars?

I used delay block to make the cars waiting in one parking lot.I used untilstopdelay() option to hold the cars and tried to specify the condition if 2nd parkinglot is free, move cars to it, at the exit of delay block.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you do to remove a car from the delay:

```
if(delay.size()>0){
   delay.stopDelay(delay.get(0));
}
```

You have to place this code somewhere in which you know space has been created in the parking lot... possibly in the block in which a car leaves the second parking lot.